# Create empty List in immutable.js

Tags: angular, typescript, immutability

I am trying to create an empty Immutable.List and to assigned a variable.

I do a git to copy  from https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md and I modify the app.component.ts file only.

Below is the sample code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, List, fromJS } from 'immutable';

export interface Person {
    name:string
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '{{sa}}'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    a1 : Person = {name:'sam'};
    sa: List<Person> = null;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.sa);
        this.sa = List([]); // How do I initialize an empty list of object Person?
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `new List()` or if you want to create a List with `a1` do `new List([this.a1])`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is below:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

    a1: Person = {name:'sam'};
    sa = List<Person>();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.sa);
    }
}
```